# What is this icon next to the inmates name tag?

Tags: prison-architect

I sometimes see this, and I'm not sure what it is. Next to an inmates name, it will have an icon (drugs in this case) and I can't seem to find online anywhere what this is, or what causes it:

[image]

I thought maybe it was "this inmate was recently caught with drugs" but it doesn't say that on his mouse-over mini-bio.

Anyone know the cause and purpose of this icon?

Answer (score 7):

**Feburary 2020**: Okay so, I somehow really overlooked this. It's actually for the rehab program, which as my 2019 update could include overdosed inmates.

Edit **September 2019**:

I believe this is purely to indicate a **Overdosed** state.

**Original Answer**:

That icon is a part of the general mood bubble. [**It shows the prisoners current need**](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Needs) (at least speculated to be part of it), in that example the prisoner needs drugs or a rehabilitation program. They will attempt to smuggle in drugs if this gets critical.

You can view the entire Prison's Needs if you have a [**Psychologist**](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Psychologist).

Mousing over a prisoner will show what need and how much they need it.

[image: Needs]

Needs marked Green are being satisfied currently, where as white ones are not.

You can see an entire overview of this in the reports in the lower right:

[image: Needs overview]

When the needs are low your prison may end up retaliating back and trying to escape or satisfy the need by smugging in drugs, or rioting.

[image: Critical need]

When they're close to breaking point the icon will change to have spiked edges around it, showing it's critical. Typically when they break they try destroying stuff in retaliation.

Comment: It seems (at least in my case) relatively rare -- I've seen prisoners complaining (with the angry bubbles) about a need for something, and it doesn't show any icons on their name tag then... is this only really visible for a drug need?

Comment: I believe so, the icon is very random when it appears... I assume it's intended I've seen a shower there before but not entirely sure why.. I actually feel it might be a bug but it seems related to the normal moods when they either broke or were about to. I left the game going over a few hours IRL and didn't see anyone else with it this time.

Comment: I think this answer is talking about the mood "bubble", rather than the pill bottle icon beside the name tag

Comment: Esh, they're related because every-time I've seen a tag next to an inmate's name it's been something like a fork, or a bottle and they've had been complaining about said need. I believe the two are related but not confirmed. I left the game going over night trying to reproduce this but no luck.

Comment: I'm going to make a bug report and maybe it's intended or maybe it's a obscure bug somewhere.. since it's so rare to happen. I have 60 hours on Steam and probably at least another 60 on the non-steam version and I've only seen this happen about 20-30 times in my many prisons.